# Expected value, dispersion and correlation coefficient of losses during the day

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value, conditional-probability, correlation

Every day a kid puts $7$ £1 coins and $9$ £2 coins in his pocket. Each day, in the morning he loses $3$ coins and in the evening of the same day he loses $5$ coins. Find his morning and evening losses' expected value $E(X)$, dispersion $D(X)$ and the correlation coefficient.

---

So, calculating his morning losses is fairly simple:

If he loses 3 coins, his losses must be $≥3$ and $≤6$ since he can lose both £1 coins and £2 coins.

If his loss is £3 in total, he must have lost $3$ £1 coins: $C(7, 3) = 35$,

If his loss is £4 in total, he must have lost $2$ £1 coins and $1$ £2 coin: $C(7, 2) · C(9, 1) = 189$,

If his loss is £5 in total, he must have lost $1$ £1 coin and $2$ £2 coins: $C(7, 1) · C(9, 2) = 252$,

If his loss is £6 in total, he must have lost $3$ £2 coins: $C(9, 3) = 84$.

There are $C(16, 3) = 560$ different combinations of him losing 3 coins.

So, $E(X) = 3 · \frac{35}{560} + 4 · \frac{189}{560} + 5 · \frac{252}{560} + 6 · \frac{84}{560} = 4.6875$

And then accordingly, $D(X) = 3^2 · \frac{35}{560} + 4^2 · \frac{189}{560} + 5^2 · \frac{252}{560} + 6^2 · \frac{84}{560} - (4.6875)^2 ≈ 0.6398 $

---

However, I can't think of a way how to calculate the evening losses for multiple reasons.

For example, if he has $7$ £1 coins in total and loses $3$ £1 coins in the morning, he can't lose 5 of them in the evening.

How do I account for this, and, most importantly - how do I calculate the correlation coefficient?

---

Edit based on the replies:

When it comes to calculating the evening losses, the morning losses must be accounted for, too.

For example, that's my calculation for the loss of £5:

• Given that he lost $3$ £1 coins in the morning, he has $4$x £1 and $9$x £2 coins.

If his loss is £5 in total, he could have lost:

$3$ £1 coins and $1$ £2 coin *or* $1$ £1 coin and $2$ £2 coins, $C(4, 3) ⋅ C(9, 1) + C(4,1) ⋅ C(9, 2) = 180$

There are $C(13, 5)$ ways to lose $5$ coins out of leftover $13$ and the probability of him losing $3$ £1 coins in the morning is $\frac{35}{560}$

Thus, $\frac{35}{560} ⋅ \frac{180}{1287} = \frac{5}{572}$

• Given that he lost $2$ £1 coins and $1$ £2 coin in the morning, he has $5$x £1 and $8$x £2 coins.

If his loss is £5 in total, he could have lost:

$5$ £1 coins *or* $3$ £1 coins and $1$ £2 coin *or* $1$ £1 coin and $2$ £2 coins, $C(5, 5) + C(5, 3) ⋅ C(8, 1) + C(5,1) ⋅ C(8, 2) = 221$

Thus, $\frac{35}{560} ⋅ \frac{221}{1287} = \frac{51}{880}$

• Given that he lost $1$ £1 coin and $2$ £2 coins in the morning, he has $6$x £1 and $7$x £2 coins.

If his loss is £5 in total, he could have lost:

$5$ £1 coins *or* $3$ £1 coins and $1$ £2 coin *or* $1$ £1 coin and $2$ £2 coins, $C(6, 5) + C(6, 3) ⋅ C(7, 1) + C(6,1) ⋅ C(7, 2) = 272$

Thus, $\frac{35}{560} ⋅ \frac{272}{1287} = \frac{68}{715}$

• Given that he lost $3$ £2 coins in the morning, he has $7$x £1 and $6$x £2 coins.

If his loss is £5 in total, he could have lost:

$5$ £1 coins *or* $3$ £1 coins and $1$ £2 coin *or* $1$ £1 coin and $2$ £2 coins, $C(7, 5) + C(7, 3) ⋅ C(6, 1) + C(7,1) ⋅ C(6, 2) = 336$

Thus, $\frac{35}{560} ⋅ \frac{336}{1287} = \frac{28}{715}$

So, the probability of his loss of £5 in the evening is $\frac{5}{572} + \frac{51}{880} + \frac{68}{715} + \frac{28}{715} = \frac{209}{1040}$

and I would go on with 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 in quite a similar manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using conditional expectation:

$Y$...pounds lost in the evening

Calculate $E(Y|X=k), k=3,4,5,6$

Then: $E(Y)=\sum_{k=3}^6E(Y|X=k)P(X=k)$

For the correlation coefficient, use the formula:

$r(X,Y)=\frac{K(X,Y)}{\sqrt{D(X)D(Y)}}$, where $K(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$

Comment: While I get the idea now, I'm still unsuccessful in calculations. When calculating each individual E(Y | X = k), what should I use in the denominator? C(13, 5) does not seem to work as the sum of all probabilities is way above 1 unlike in the morning calculations where (35/560) + (189/560) + (252/560) + (84/560) = 1. I could post all of my calculations if needed, by the way.

Comment: It should be C(13,5) and the calculations are the same as for X except you have four different cases now. Maybe you made some trivial calculating errors.

Comment: I have edited the original post with some of my calculations, can you please check it out?

Comment: Yes, it look right. It’s a bit tedious but I dont see any other way. And I’m not sure about the approach from the other answer.

Comment: but then the probability of the loss being £6 is (11591/34320), probability of £7 is (2143/4290), and with that (209/1040) + (11591/34320) + (2143/4290) > 1 and I haven't even included £8, £9 and £10 yet.

Comment: Oh I see it. When you were going through possibilities for 5£ in the evening, you didnt take in account that he loses 5 coins. You were only looking at combinations that give you 5£ and not also that you need exactly 5 coins. That’s why you had too many combinations and the probabilities went above 1.

Comment: Good catch! Would've never noticed it myself, now everything seems to be okay! One last question though - how should I calculate E(XY)?

Comment: By calculating the distribution of XY. You know all possible values of X and Y and their probabilities, therefore you can easily find all possible values of values of XY and the correspondent probabilities. But be careful: if e.g. X=4 and Y=5, then P(XY=20)=P(X=4)P(Y=5|X=4)+… (Use conditional probability with Y because X and Y are not independent)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the answer. But as the above answer suggest using conditional expectation we will get the answer. But the calculation would be tedious. I have this idea.

If this equation holds true;
$$ \text{E}[ \text{losing 8 coins} ] = \text{E}[ \text{losing 3 coins}] + \text{E} [\text{losing 5 coins}]$$

So this will make a calculation litter easier than the method using conditional probabilities. I don't know whether this above equation holds true.[I have no access to comment so I wrote an answer just correct me if I am wrong].

This works for $$
\text{E}[2] = 2 * \text{E}[1]
$$
$$\frac{\binom{9}2}{\binom{16}2}*4+\frac{\binom{9}1 *\binom{7}1 }{\binom{16}2}*3 + \frac{\binom{7}2}{\binom{16}2}*2=\frac{375}{120}=2*(\frac{7}{16}*1+\frac{9}{16}*2 $$)

Comment: This looks pretty good. Although, is there a way to calculate dispersion and correlation coefficient, then?

Comment: After getting E(losing 8 coins) , for dispersion try using another formula(you used E[X^2]-(E[X])^2 ) .Using that find mean of square differences, where you need square and add 9 terms and divide by 8. var(losing 8) - var(losing 3) = var(losing 3). you will get the dispersion